# Android AWS TransferService not working in API level 26 and above

Tags: android, amazon-s3, kotlin, aws-sdk

Tried to upload some image into the s3 bucket of AWS.
Worked fine below the API level 26 but shows error
**Unable to execute HTTP request: timeout** from API level 26 and above.

Used sdk :

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.13.+'
implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.13.+@aar') { transitive = true }
implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.13.+@aar') { transitive = true }
```

I have started service from Application like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(AWS_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, AWS_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(channel)
        val notification = Notification.Builder(applicationContext, AWS_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(AWS_NOTIFICATION_TITLE)
                .setContentText(AWS_NOTIFICATION_CONTENT)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon)
                .build()
        val tsIntent = Intent(applicationContext, TransferService::class.java)
        tsIntent.putExtra(TransferService.INTENT_KEY_NOTIFICATION, notification)
        tsIntent.putExtra(TransferService.INTENT_KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, AWS_NOTIFICATION_ID)
        tsIntent.putExtra(TransferService.INTENT_KEY_REMOVE_NOTIFICATION, true)
        applicationContext.startForegroundService(tsIntent)
    } else {
        applicationContext.startService(Intent(applicationContext, TransferService::class.java))
    }
```

Appreciate both solutions with or without using **TransferService**.

Comment: Did you added `Network security config` in your app for `HTTP url`? because if your url is based on `HTTP` then it will not work.

Comment: Yes I have added

Comment: Also check` <domain includeSubdomains="true">abc.xyy</domain>` only add url without `http://` prefix and don't mention any `api` name after url into postfix.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But does these setting matters on OS level above 26?

Comment: Yes! if are not setting `NSC` or not mentioned your `HTTP url` properly in `NSC` then it will not reply to your server `request` as per rule in `API` 26,27,28,29

Answer (score 1):

For supporting **TransferService** on **Oreo** and above need to start **ForegroundService**

**TransferNetworkLossHandler**, a broadcast receiver that listens for network connectivity changes is introduced in **2.11.0**. **TransferNetworkLossHandler** pauses the on-going transfers when the network goes offline and resumes the transfers that were paused when the network comes back online. **TransferService** registers the **TransferNetworkLossHandler** when the service is created and de-registers the handler when the service is destroyed.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val channel = NotificationChannel(AWS_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, 
    AWS_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)

    (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as 
    NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(channel)

    val notification = Notification.Builder(applicationContext, 
    AWS_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
         .setContentTitle(AWS_NOTIFICATION_TITLE)
         .setContentText(AWS_NOTIFICATION_CONTENT)
         .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon)
         .setAutoCancel(true)

    val tsIntent = Intent(applicationContext, TransferService::class.java)
    tsIntent.putExtra(TransferService.INTENT_KEY_NOTIFICATION, notification.build())
    tsIntent.putExtra(TransferService.INTENT_KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID,AWS_NOTIFICATION_ID)
    tsIntent.putExtra(TransferService.INTENT_KEY_REMOVE_NOTIFICATION, true)

    applicationContext.startForegroundService(tsIntent)
} else {
   applicationContext.startService(Intent(applicationContext, 
   TransferService::class.java))
}
```

For more details see: [aws-storage](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/storage)